# Ошибка в программе "Прекращена работа программы proga.exe"

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

После ввода строки и нажатия enter выводится сообщение ...

> "Прекращена работа программы proga.exe"

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. И ещё, может существует способ (не через прерывания) сделать паузу перед закрытием консоли?

```
.data
dest db "Не удалось назначить консоль :( ",0
descrIn DD 0 ; перменная  для дескриптора ввода
descrOut DD 0 ; перменная для дескриптора вывода
stroka db 80 dup(0)
readBuf db 80 dup(0); для вводимой строки
kolChrs DD 0; количество реально прочитанных символов
start:
call AllocConsole ; вывоз для функции назначающей консоль
cmp eax,0 
je error ; если не удалось назначить консоль (еах = 0) - ошибка
invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ; запрашиваем идентификатор буфера ввода (дескриптор консоли)
mov descrOut, EAX
invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
mov descrIn, EAX
invoke ReadConsole, descrIn, offset readBuf, 80, offset kolChrs,0
mov ECX,kolChrs
mov EDI,0
mov ESI,0
M1:
mov AL, readBuf[ESI]
mov stroka[EDI],AL
add ESI,2
inc EDI
loop M1
invoke WriteConsole, descrOut, offset stroka, kolChrs, offset kolChrs,MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess,0
error:
invoke MessageBox,0, addr dest, NULL,MB_OK
mov ah,1
int 21h
invoke ExitProcess,0
end start
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь отладчиком. Думаете, методом пристального взгляда ошибка отыщется легче?

Comment: @StPeLka, с масмом не работаю, но: 1. по идее секция .data не доступна для выполнения, а у вас в ней код; 2. под Windows в пользовательском режиме нельзя использовать прерывания.

Comment: Чтобы сделать паузу перед выходом, либо используйте тот же ReadConsole, либо делайте задержку с помощью функции sleep.

Comment: действительно проблема из-за прерывания, заменила на invoke Sleep,100 и всё работает) огромное спасибо) 
на счёт использования отладчика тоже дельный совет, осталось научиться им пользоваться))

Comment: @StPeLka, перенесу комментарии в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что заметил - у вас единственная секция, которая называется ".data". Это может не вызвать проблем, а может и вызвать, т.к. секция данных может быть защищена от запуска.

Второе - вы используете прерывание int 21h. Под Windows в пользовательском режиме нельзя использовать прерывания (ну кроме разве что int3 при отладке).

Для добавления паузы перед завершением программы можно использовать ту же функцию ReadConsole, она будет ждать нажатия Enter, или использовать функцию sleep.